# ms-access: rowsource question

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i am a vb.net programmer, and i have done lots of VBA with excel. i am a beginner at access.

someone has given me an access database to debug and i am lost.

i succesfully made it connect to a local mysql database.

i have a listbox on a form that has a rowsource attached to a query called listbox. here's a picture of the properties of the listbox:
[alt text http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/936/listboxotherrelationsls.png](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/936/listboxotherrelationsls.png)

there are some issues with displaying the results of the query because the query is too complex and incorrectly structured. when there are fewer than a few results from the query, they display in the listbox without a problem, but when there are more than 4-5 results, it leaves it blank; however, i know that it returned the correct number because it left the correct number of rows (which are blank in the listbox). therefore, instead of trying to fix the huge messy query, i would like to feed all the rows in a string, and then feed them back into the listbox.

can someone help me with this? when you reply please put your responses in laymen's terms because as i said i am an access beginner.

this is what the listbox looks like when it doesnt want to display results:
[alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/4632/fullscreencapture122220.jpg](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/4632/fullscreencapture122220.jpg)

Comment: If the query / sql string is not working properly as seems to be the case from your comment below, it could easily be the reason your listbox is displaying nothing.

Comment: So how many columns in the query? Ten?

Comment: Seems like bad SQL, and until we see the full SQL, nobody's going to be able to help. I am a bit surprised by a 10-column listbox -- maybe you should use a subform? But in any case, none of the solutions (including the ADO solution) is going to work without a valid SQL statement. We can't help troubleshoot that without seeing it in full.

Comment: correct bad SQL. i dont believe i will be troubleshooting SQL, i just want to solve this problem using a dumb approach since i do not have time to debug the SQL

Comment: So does the SQL work when you run the query all by itself?  You state above "it is displaying 3 results" therefore the query is working.

Comment: If you don't post the SQL we won't be able to judge how it is interacting with the properties set for your listbox. It's no skin off my nose if you don't post it, but if you want an answer that solves you're problem, I think you need to post the listbox SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something on these lines:

```
''Some notes on declarations for ADO recpdset and connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection

''Set the connection object to the access project
''connection. You may wish to use a connection string (see below)
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

''Open the recordset, change the sql string to whatever string is used
''to populate the listbox
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Testaccess", cn

''Convert the recordset to a string delimited by row and column with ;
''This is the delimiter needed by Access for the listbox with value data
strlist = rs.GetString(, , ";", ";")

''Set the rowsource of the listbox to the string
Me.List0.RowSource = strlist

''It would be easiest to set these before the run
''None of this is necessary, it can all be set as properties 
''of the listbox before the code is run
''Column count, same as number of fields
Me.List0.ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
''List type is values
Me.List0.RowSourceType = "Value List"

''This is just a set of 1cms for each column
For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
    strWidths = strWidths & ";1cm"
Next

''here we go, all columns set to 1cm width
Me.List0.ColumnWidths = Mid(strWidths, 2)
```

connection string: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: rs.Open "SELECT users.id, users.first, users.last, chavrusas.luser_type AS user_type, chavrusas.id, users.title, users.city, users.state, users.home_phone, users.email  FROM Users INNER JOIN chavrusas ON Users.id=chavrusas.luser_id  WHERE ((chavrusas.ruser_id)=id_txt and chavrusas.ended=false) AND (chavrusas.luser_type)<>(chavrusas.ruser_type) AND NOT ((chavrusas.luser_type)='teacher' AND (chavrusas.ruser_type)='student') AND NOT ((chavrusas.ruser_type)='teacher' AND (chavrusas.luser_type)='student'); UNION SELECT users.id, users.first,et cetcetc ..... "no value given on one of the parameters"

Comment: the only thing i can do is copy and paste that code, i dont know what anything means so you will have to simplify it and provide clear instructions for every line

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameter is probably from the Where statement. If you refer to a form, keep it outside the quotes. Please post the full SQL in your post if you need help with it.

Comment: Remou, nothing personal but yikes this is an ugly solution when it should just work.

Comment: Tony Toews, the op says"i would like to feed all the rows in a string, and then feed them back into the listbox" and sometimes I give people what they ask for, and let them decide whether it is a good idea or not.

Comment: After all, that is the line that makes this question different from other listbox questions and Stackoverflow is not a forum, it is a question and answer site.

Comment: Remou, the OP is wrong.   He/she should be figuring out what the real problem is instead of masking it.

Comment: I am not sure that we would have got the information that the SQL is not working so quickly without this step. Sometimes it is necessary to take a slightly longer road.

Comment: I'm with Tony on this one. I also question why someone has 10 columns in a listbox. I've occasionally used a listbox like a subform, but when you've got more than 5 or 6 columns, it seems to me like it's no longer really a list at all, but a data display control, and probably should be a subform.

Comment: david and tony, i really appreciate your responses; however,  if you know the answer to my question please help!

Comment: Nobody can answer your question without seeing the full SQL of your listbox's rowsource, which you seem reluctant to post. There's no guarantee we can solve the problem with the SQL, but without it, it's impossible (unless someone just happens to guess the correct answer).

Comment: I've already answered your questions but you haven't stated that you've checked them.  That is the hoftix and check the number of columns.

Comment: Remou, the OP stated "it is displaying 3 results ". That tells me his query is working.

Comment: tony i did check the number of columns

Comment: Ok, so respond accordingly to my posting.  And what about the missing column widths and the hotfix?  Did you check those?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the Column Count property is correct.  That is are there ten columns or fields in the query?

Also you should really put ten widths in the Column Widths property even if they are 0" width.  I only see seven in there.

Is this Access 2003 with SP3?  If so see this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945674). Combo box controls and list box controls display no value or incorrect values in Access 2003 after you install Office 2003 Service Pack 3

Comment: how do i find out which SP version it is?

Comment: by the way ive updated my question, please look at the last graphic

Comment: Check the 'About' link in the 'Help' Menu.

Comment: Your last graphic doesn't tell us anything.  Have you checked the items I've listed in my posting?